# Puma not running in production ec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, puma, capistrano3

I am trying to deploy my website to amazon ec2 using nginx,puma and capistrano i followed this tutorial https://medium.com/@henslejoseph/deployment-a-rails-app-to-ec2-using-bitbucket-and-semaphoreci-d539bea90db3 the application got deployed to server but when i trying to access it via browser by going to website url it says This site can’t be reached.The next thing i tried is checking the nginx and the puma logs i dont find anythig in nginx logs but in puma_access.log there is error Errno::EADDRINUSE: Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 3000.After this i tried checking if any process is using the port 3000 using lsof -wni tcp:3000  and netstat -an | grep 3000 but the output was empty seems there is no process attached to port.
I am trying to debug it from 3 days but still clue less what is going.Any help is greatly appreciated  I am just enclosing my all my config files for reference.

**capfile**
    # Load DSL and set up stages
    require "capistrano/setup"

```
# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

    require "capistrano/scm/git"
    install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git


# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
require "capistrano/rvm"
# require "capistrano/rbenv"
# require "capistrano/chruby"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
require "capistrano/puma"
# require "capistrano/passenger"

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

**deploy.rb**

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.10.1"

set :application, "myappname"
set :repo_url, "myapp_url"

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

set :branch, :deployment_work

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
# set :deploy_to, "/var/www/my_app_name"
 set :deploy_to, '/home/yogesh/myapp_name'
 # set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml"

set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'config/application.yml')

set :rvm_type, :user

set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.3.3'

set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')
set :keep_releases, 3
# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system"

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for local_user is ENV['USER']
# set :local_user, -> { `git config user.name`.chomp }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

# Uncomment the following to require manually verifying the host key before first deploy.
# set :ssh_options, verify_host_key: :secure

    # Pume config
    set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
    set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
    set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
    set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"    #accept array for multi-bind
    set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/puma.rb"
    set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"
    set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
    set :puma_role, :app
    set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
    set :puma_threads, [0, 8]
    set :puma_workers, 0
    set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
    set :puma_init_active_record, true
    set :puma_preload_app, false
```

**production.rb**

```
set :stage, :production
    # Replace this EC2 server's public IP with your EC2 server's public IP
    # Replace this user ('sarmad') with the one you created on your EC2 instance
    server 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx', user: 'yogesh', roles: %w{web app db}

    set :ssh_options,{ forward_agent: true, user: 'yogesh', keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa) }
```

**puma.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma

directory '/home/yogesh/myapp_name/current'
rackup "/home/yogesh/myapp_name/current/config.ru"
environment 'production'

pidfile "/home/yogesh/myapp_name/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "/home/yogesh/myapp_name/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state"
stdout_redirect '/home/yogesh/myapp_name/shared/log/puma_error.log', '/home/yogesh/myapp_name/shared/log/puma_access.log', true


threads 0,8

bind 'unix:///home/yogesh/myapp_name/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock'

workers 0



prune_bundler


on_restart do
  puts 'Refreshing Gemfile'
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = ""
end
```

**nginxconfig**

```
upstream app {
      # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
      server unix:///home/yogesh/myapp_name/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;
      root /home/yogesh/myapp_name/current/public;
      try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
      location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_pass http://app;
      }
      location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
      }
      error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
      client_max_body_size 4G;
      keepalive_timeout 10;
    }
```

Can someone help me where i am going wrong have tried all stackoverflow questions and googled a lot from 3 days still no idea whats wrong with my config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: After a lot of research i got the solution 
all you have to do is ensure that the default file in sites_available folder should also be available in sites_enabled folder.This default file ensures that the website is enabled.If the default file is not available it seems like nginx is not listening on port 80.